# Compute girth of a graph using BFS

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question related to graph theory.
How can I find the girth of a graph by using BFS algorithm ?
I have been trying to find a way for 2 days... but I can't come up with something.

Hope you guys have an idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/234247/Winter2003-2004/ho/WCFiles/Girth.pdf.

It has a nice `O(VE)` algorithm.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I have a confusion. How is O(V(V+E)) = O(VE) ?

Comment: O(V(V+E))=O(V^2+VE). In general, VE grows faster than V^2, so it is fair to state O(V(V+E)) = O(VE), although for clarity I would have preferred O(V^2+VE) since computationally the term V^2 does matter.